# Package Load Failure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, package

I recently installed `VS Team System 2008`, while having `VS 2010` installed on `Windows 7x64`

On First-run i get the following type of error

[image: VSErr1]

However i receive multiple of them:

- ReportDesignerPackage
- DataWarehouse VSIntergration layer
- Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package...
- Ect...(+2 More)

How do i fix this, and how do i **prevent** this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try reinstall VS2010 now?
Both VS2010 and Vs2008 works fine on my machines if VS2010 is installed after 2008.